# What do we know about Cyclops' eye dimension?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, cyclops

So while reading through some old questions and answers I came across this answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/33326/44765

In it, it is said that Cyclops doesn't feel recoil from his eye beams because

> "Cyclop's eyes (in later canon) are actually interdimensional portals,
>   gateways to a dimension full of this strange concussive energy"

Is there any more information about this dimension?  Is the dimension useful for anything outside of his blasts?  Have other mutants/people been able to tap into the dimension to access the energy?  Assuming you didn't get instantly vaporized from the energy there, is it possible to go to the dimension?

Comment: This question reads more like a conversation starter rather than a specific question / answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'll see if I can rephrase the question. I'm looking for more info on the dimension his blasts come from.

Comment: You are entering a dimension of ruby red. A dimension where the laws of physics and energy conservation hold no sway. A dimension created solely for one man's ability to shoot optic blasts. You are entering... the Cyclops Zone.

Comment: Based on depiction in the films, for example, https://38.media.tumblr.com/d395cc1fc8d675f593a2045218492d45/tumblr_nptrtkrIF71uqkpjlo2_400.gif, I'd say his eyes are the same dimension as anyone else's -- typical around 24mm  (https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Human_eye#Structure)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### We know almost nothing about the energy which Scott Summer's mutation allows him to access through his eyes. The energy appears as a red light but has the potential of delivering a kinetic payload equal to hundreds or even thousands of pounds of dynamite.

Described in several different ways but ultimately settled on as:

> - Cyclops possesses the mutant ability to project a beam of heatless ruby-colored concussive force from his eyes, which act as inter-dimensional apertures between this universe and another.
> - Cyclops' body constantly absorbs ambient energy, such as sunlight, from his environment into his body's cells that allows him to open the apertures.
> - Cyclops' mind generates a psionic field that is attuned to the forces that maintain the apertures. **[REF: Marvel.com > Cyclops](http://marvel.com/universe/Cyclops_(Scott_Summers)#ixzz3dXIiF0Pl)**

- **As to the dimension/universe which powers his ruby energy blast: No. We've never been there.**
- Very little has ever been mentioned about it beyond its physical effects. Havok (Scott's brother, Alex) is mostly immune to the energy from there and his other brother Vulcan is able to manipulate the energy from this dimension.

**The beam has several properties which make it unlike electromagnetic radiation in our world.**

- It can be bounced off of multiple surfaces and deliver its energetic payload only to the target at the very end or any target he deems necessary along the way.

[image]

- It can be blocked by material whose properties resemble ruby quartz, a naturally occurring mineral found on Earth. It concussive power is rendered inert. It is the material which Scott uses to allow him to see normally from behind his ruby-quartz sunglasses or combat visor.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. I was really hoping for something else but I guess not everyone (the writers) is as intrigued as I am :)

Comment: They may be as intrigued, but you have to ask yourself. A dimension of pure hostile and devastatingly powerful energy. Why would you want to send anyone there and how would they survive? Unless their is an intelligence behind it (such as the Realm of Cytorrak) it would not be a place most beings could survive to write about.

Comment: If it can be directed to deliver the payload, as you put it, only to certain targets, then it can at least be manipulated if not actually operate intelligently.